# Implementing Gaussian elimination with partial pivoting

Tags: matlab, gaussian

I am writing a program to implement Gaussian elimination with partial pivoting in MATLAB. I created an integer array to store the interchange of rows, instead of directly exchanging the rows.

However, I could not obtain the correct result and I could not figure out the problem. How should I modify my code to get the right answer?

```
A=[1, -2, 1; 2, 1, -3; 4, -7, 1];
b=[0, 5, 1];
b=b';

function x = GE(A,b)

[m,n]= size(A); 
if m ~= n
  disp('Not a square');
end

for p=1:n
   array(p)=p;
endfor

A = [A,b];      

%elimination
for i = 1:n-1
    pivot = i;
    %select pivot
    for j = i+1:n
        if  abs(A(array(i),i)) < abs(A(array(i),i)) %row interchange
            temp = array(i);
            array(i) = array(j);
            array(j) = temp;
        end
    end

    while (pivot <= n && A(pivot,i)== 0)
        pivot = pivot+1;
    end
    if pivot > n
        disp('No unique solution');
        break
    else
        if pivot > i
            tem = array(i);
            array(i) = pivot
            pivot= tem;
        end
    end

    for j = i+1:n
        m = -A(array(j),i)/A(array(i),i);
        for k = i+1:n+1 
            A(array(j),k) = A(array(j),k) + m*A(array(i),k);
        end
    end
end

if A(n,n) == 0
    disp('No unique solution');
    return
end

%backward substitution
x(n) = A(array(n),n+1)/A(array(n),n);
for i = n - 1:-1:1
    sum = 0;
    for j = i+1:n
        sum = sum + A(array(i),j)*x(j);
    end
    x(i) = (A(array(i),n+1) - sum)/A(array(i),i);
end

endfunction
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is pretty simple.  You're not pivoting properly - specifically here inside your `if` statement:

```
for j = i+1:n
    if  abs(A(array(i),i)) < abs(A(array(i),i)) %row interchange <-------
        temp = array(i);
        array(i) = array(j);
        array(j) = temp;

    end
end
```

Your check to see which coefficient to pivot from is not correct because you are using the index `i` for checking along the columns when you need to use `j`.  Therefore, simply change the other side of your Boolean condition so that it uses `j`:

```
for j = i+1:n
    if  abs(A(array(i),i)) < abs(A(array(j),j)) %// CHANGE HERE
        temp = array(i);
        array(i) = array(j);
        array(j) = temp;

    end
end
```

With your example `A` and `b`, the answer I get is `x = [2 1 0]`, which agrees with MATLAB's `ldivide` operation: `x = A \ b`.